# SQL Query using multiple JOINS without sub query

Tags: sql, postgresql

Lets say I have three tables with these columns,

```
      Players - id, name
      Events - id, name
      Games - first_player_id, second_player_id, event_id.
```

And I need the `players` details who are playing in a `game` which is happening in an `event`.
And I could write query like,

```
SELECT players.id, events.id as event_id, 
(SELECT name as player_one_name from players where id = games.first_player_id), 
(SELECT name as player_two_name from players where id = games.second_player_id), 
games.id as game_id  
    FROM events 
    INNER JOIN games on events.id = games.event_id 
    INNER JOIN players on games.first_player_id = players.id;"
```

Here I am using two sub queries to fetch players name. **And it gives correct results**. Can this query be optimized? For ex, can I remove any `subquery` or `innerjoin` ?

FYI, I use `PostgreSQL` database.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not want sub queries in your select statement then you must provide a join for each subset. Since your database is set oriented the two INNER JOINS would prove more efficient.

```
SELECT players.id, events.id as event_id,
     player_one_name=player_one.name,
     player_tow_name=player_two.name
FROM events 
INNER JOIN games on events.id = games.event_id 
INNER JOIN players player_one on games.first_player_id = player_one.id
INNER JOIN players player_two on games.second_player_id = player_two.id
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Will accept yours as an answer in 30 seconds :P :D

Answer (score 1):

You must do a join for each foreign key

```
SELECT players_a.id, events.id as event_id, 
players_a.name as player_one_name,
players_b.name as player_two_name,
games.id as game_id  
    FROM events 
    INNER JOIN games on events.id = games.event_id 
    INNER JOIN players players_a on games.first_player_id = players.id
    INNER JOIN players players_b on games.first_player_id = players.id
```

Answer (score 0):

The currently accepted answer is right about joining the `players` table twice, but mostly wrong otherwise. This would work:

```
SELECT e.id AS event_id
      ,g.id AS game.id
      ,p1.name AS first_player
      ,p2.name AS second_player
FROM   events e
LEFT   JOIN games    g ON g.event_id = e.id 
LEFT   JOIN players p1 ON p1.id = g.first_player_id 
LEFT   JOIN players p2 ON p2.id = g.second_player_id;
```

- Use `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN` to cover the cases where an event does not have a game or a game does not have both players (yet).
- Use table aliases to simplify your syntax. To join the same table twice you also *need* at least one table alias.
  After attaching an alias to a table in the `FROM` list, only *that* alias is visible in your query, not the original name of the table.
- [Study the manual for details.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html)

Comment: My aim is to fetch PLAYERS who are playing in a game in an event. So I need only rows if the EVENT have PLAYERS and GAME have that EVENT. If I do LEFT JOIN, I will also get GAMES and EVENTS with no players right?

Comment: @BharathMg: That's right. Just Drop the `LEFT` then.